# add tooltips to programmatically created controls

Tags: c#, tooltip

I have a bunch of buttons created on a winforms c# app. I have created them using the  following code

```
int s = 0;//28 buttons
        ButtonNameArray barray = new ButtonNameArray();
        frontPanelButtons fpb = new frontPanelButtons();
        int xLoc = fpb.xLoc(fpb);
        int yLoc = fpb.yLoc(fpb);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Name = barray.getName(btn.Name, s);
                btn.Text = barray.getText(btn.Text, s);
                btn.Width = fpb.btnWide(fpb);
                btn.Height = fpb.btnHigh(fpb);
                btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xLoc, yLoc);
                Controls.Add(btn);
                xLoc += 100;
                s++;
            }
            yLoc += 31;
            xLoc = fpb.xLoc(fpb);
        }
```

And I would like to add a unique tooltip to each button but can't figure out how to do it. Could anyone please supply help/the answer? Many thanks.

Comment: http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-3307/Button-ToolTips.htm

Comment: why not just tack on   btn.ToolTip = "some other value";   while you are at it..  It could be based on the x/y location, button number as generated, whatever.

Comment: Do you want one tooltip per button or one tooltip for all buttons?

Comment: I want one tooltip per button.  So 28 unique tooltips.

Comment: Why? Are you sure you need 28 tooltips? You know you can assign a different tooltip text for each control even with _only one_ tooltip.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
//...
ToolTip ttip = new ToolTip();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        // ...
        ttip.SetToolTip(btn, "Some text on my tooltip.");
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Works for vb.net too